# Divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot.....(2n)}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I was solving practice problems for my upcoming calculus 1 final and came across this problem. I'm honestly still a little lost about the series and ratio tests.

> The problem itself is $$\sum_{n=1}^∞\frac{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot.....(2n)}{n!}$$

I identified  $$a_n = \frac{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot \ldots (2n)}{n!}$$ but I'm not sure if a $$a_{n+1} = \frac{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot \ldots (2n)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$ or something else?
Please help evaluate the limit using, $$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|.$$ Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a Mathjax tutorial

Comment: $a_{n+1}$ would be $\frac{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots (2n) \cdot (2(n+1))}{(n+1)!}$

Comment: Hint: if you factor a $2$ out of each term in the numerator, can you observe any cancellation?

Comment: Thanks for Mathjax; this is much easier to read now

Comment: ISTM that this series sum is undefined, because the $a_n$ sequence grows without bound.   What am I missing?

Comment: @Scott I don't think you're missing anything. The question had a misleading title I believe.

Answer (score 4):

$$
a_n=\frac{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots 2n}{n!}=\frac{2^nn!}{n!}=2^n
$$
hence
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=2
$$
so the series diverges (but it was clearer just by looking at $a_n$ itself).

---

If you don't want to factor the 2 in the numerator, just write
$$
a_{n+1}=\frac{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots 2n\cdot (2(n+1))}{(n+1)!}
=\frac{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots 2n}{n!}\frac{2(n+1)}{n+1}
=2a_n
$$